# Fatal PHP Errors in IIS 7.5

Tags: php, ajax, error-handling, iis-7.5

I'd like to see any PHP errors that are occuring, ie the `"Expected ; on line 5 of myfile.php"` sort of thing. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out how to see this information.

I've set E_ALL, display_errors ON, friendly error messages are turned off, IIS is set to pass-through on errors, what am I missing?

Syntax errors used to show up as stated above on any page; they no longer do. We moved the server to a localhost for development, and I guess didn't mimic exactly the server config. Now I'm stumped.

Tried on IE and Chrome, neither of which show the errors.

Errors are logged in PHP's log file, but I'd still like them to be displayed on the page; at least for now.

**UPDATE:**

Just tried adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` directly into the requested page, and it now works.. but why? Why does it need to be set locally? My PHP.ini file has this declared already.

Comment: What is the problem exactly, that you are calling the file from ajax or that you moved to another server?

Comment: Both; I cannot debug my AJAX because a fatal error occurs, but I have no real way of figuring out what the error is without the errors. The problem I see is that my error reporting does not show fatal errors; I need it to. The other server showed fatal errors in the browser, but I don't know which configs lead to this behavior, nor have I been able to figure it out online.

Comment: That still does not make sense as php errors are not displayed in the browsers if the script is called using ajax. Perhaps my answer can help you out.

Comment: They're not displayed in the browser, I know, but they used to be displayed in the response, which I could then parse into the calling page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like this is half my own stupidity, half the cloudiness of automatic installations.

Turns out there were TWO php.ini files, and that IIS used the one located within the `iis express` directory on the main drive, instead of the regular `PHP` directory.

So to anybody else having this problem, I'm providing the full list of crap you have to wade through to get the errors as you would like:

**1)** [Turn off the IIS default error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345532/turn-iis7-http-error-handling-off)

**2)** [Disable 'friendly error messages'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778248%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

**3)** Ensure you are using the CORRECT php.ini file, and change the parameters as needed. Specifically [`error_reporting` and `display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

All of this is necessary before seeing all of the error messages you need right in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of the question; to see the errors when using ajax: You can use the developer tools of your browser to see the exact response from the server.

In FireBug for Firefox for example, you go to the `Net` tab and there you see all ajax request popping up as they happen. Opening one of these requests will give you an overview with more tabs like `Response` and `HTML`.

Comment: I also cannot see the errors in an erroneous php page which I view directly; the problem (as I just found out a moment ago) is with the error displays themselves; they don't exist. It's not showing me parse errors.

Comment: @StuckAtWork Then you should probably edit your question as the title and the first part seem to suggest that it is related to ajax.

Comment: Will do; I assumed it was an issue between ajax at the beginning, but did some elementary checks and found that no parse/fatal errors are displayed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
error_reporting (-1);
```

E_ALL isn't really "all" for php < 5.4.

Also, make sure 'display_errors' is set.

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

Comment: I've done the latter already; textStatus is just 'error' and errorThrown is 'Internal Server Error'. I've also not been able to get any useful information out of the jqXHR.responseText because the response is actually null; a fatal error occurs and that is returned instead of the error, which is what I need. See my edited question, as I've narrowed down the issue.

Comment: Ah, so this probably has more to do with your server setup. Do you have a custom error handler or are you using the PHP default? Also, which version of php?

Comment: According to the `news.txt` of the PHP file, `21 Feb 2013, PHP 5.3.22`. No custom handlers. I've tried something as simple as `<?php echo "This is correct"; echo "This is not; ?>` in order to get a parse error on a basically empty PHP file, no errors were reported, but no output whatsoever. With friendly error messages ON, it's just an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Still no luck. In my php.ini, I believe I have it set as E_ALL | E_STRICT

Comment: The `PHP 5.3.22` should have flagged me.. I knew I had a newer version than that. See my self-answer.