# ASP.NET MVC 4 Catch-all only firing on local, not on remote requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

In an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, we have set up a catch-all route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
     name: "UnKnown",  
     url: "{*url}",  
     defaults: new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "UnknownUrl" });
```

The UnknownUrl method in the CatchAllController correctly loads its view in our development environment.

However, the production IIS 7.5 shows its **standard 404 page if a non-existing remote request** arrives. A **local request**, sent using RDP on the server itself, **works fine**.

The web.config is set tp

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

**What other difference is there between a local call and a remote call?** How can we make the MVC HttpHandler catch those requests?

A **hint** might be that we were also unable to make the IIS show any detailed status 500 error messages when called remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had problems with IIS showing default errors instead of .NET errors, which I've fixed with the following in `system.webServer` in the web.config:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```

I think this would happen if in your `UnknownUrl` action you are setting `Response.StatusCode = 404;`. By default IIS sees you are returning an error code so shows a default error message, which you can override with that config setting.

I'm not sure this would be different on local v remote but could be worth a try.

Comment: Very cool. That did it for us and also solved the error issue!

Comment: BTW, in order to allow settings in the httpErrors section, in IIS 7.0 one may have to execute cd C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv and appcmd unlock config /section:httpErrors as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345532/turn-iis7-http-error-handling-off.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting the host header - I believe this is what causes the difference between local and production:

```
new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "UnknownUrl", host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host}
```

Register this route from Application_BeginRequest of `Global.asax`. Also, ensure that this is done only once - perhaps by a check similar to:

```
if (routes["UnKnown"] == null)
        {
            routes.MapRoute( 
                name: "UnKnown",  
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "UnknownUrl", host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host}
            );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. We've added this, but it throws an error, saying "Request is not available in this context" (in German: "Anforderung steht in diesem Kontext nicht zur Verfügung"). Any ideas?

Comment: Oh okay, that's because HttpContext wouldn't be available during Application_Start. You could probably map this 'catch-all' route within "void Application_BeginRequest()" in your Global.asax.

Comment: Too bad - it's still not working. Placing it into Application_BeginRequest didn't work, so we set the host manually by reading the web.config. But still the old 404.