# Custom Error Works with Errors, But Fails On 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application I have enabled the custom errors in the web.config. I want all errors to redirect to one page.

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
```

This redirects to the `~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` page just fine when I do

```
throw new Exception();
```

But when I surf to `site/Home/Bla` it redirects me to an IIS general 404 error page and not my custom one.

I tried to add

```
private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}
```

to the `Global.asax`, but to no avail.

Does anybody know what might be the problem? (If you need more information, then aks and ye shall receive.)

Comment: Here's an approach using a generic error controller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. Thanks to Jason to point me in the right direction. :) Thanks to him I got on the right track to find it.

Answer found in [StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770265/2182264)

Apparently I pointed to a controller and an action and if you specify `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` on the `customErrors` node, then the redirect uses an older library to get the content. That should be a page and can't be a mvc route.

So either you specify an actual page or you use the `redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"` option. The page needs to be a .htm or .html page, a .cshtml isn't accepted either.

Comment: +1: Thanks for posting your solution.  I wish more people would do that.

Comment: I know, bugs me too. That's why I make sure that when I post a question, I check back until I get the answer and update it. And I'm not afraid to give credit where it's due. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" />

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <!-- Avoid IIS messing with custom errors http://stackoverflow.com/a/2345742/426840 -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

  </system.webServer>
```